# Object transform.localScale not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding some objects in the game but for same reason, the first object I add from a generic list do not change in localScale.

As you can see from the image below, the console displays that localScale is correct, but when you look at the gameview and inspector, the object has a Vector.zero localScale.  What's weird is that all the other properties of the object is correct (i.e. object.name is correctly name 3, 7).

The objects after the first are all displayed correctly as well.

**Update:** If I don't use  `Queue<GameObject> tile = new Queue<GameObject>()`, things work normally..

[image]

Here's the script:

```
public void animateGrid(List<int[]> matchTile, List<int[]> moveTile, List<int[]> appendTile){
        animating = true;

        Queue<GameObject> tile = new Queue<GameObject>();

        Debug.Log ("MatchTile count: " + matchTile.Count);
        Debug.Log ("AddTile count: " + appendTile.Count);

        foreach(int[] i in matchTile){
            tile.Enqueue(getGameObject(i[0], i[1]));
            match (tile.Peek());
        }

        Debug.Log ("tile: " + tile.Count);

        foreach(int[] j in appendTile){
            int x1 = j[0], y1 = j[1], 
                x2 = j[2], y2 = j[3];

            GameObject gameObj = tile.Dequeue();

            Debug.Log ("tileNo");

            append (    gameObj, 
                        getCoordinateFromGrid(x2, y2), 
                        x2, y2, 
                        grid.filled[x1, y1]
            );
        }
    ...
}

private void match(GameObject tile){
    Hashtable optional = new Hashtable();
    optional.Add("ease", LeanTweenType.easeInBounce);

    LeanTween.scale(tile, Vector3.zero, 0.05f, optional);   
    tile.SetActive(false);
}

private void append(GameObject tile, Vector3 position, int x, int y, int type){
    float tileSize = 1f / 9f;

    tile.renderer.material.color    =   getColor(type);
    tile.tag                        =   getType(type);
    tile.name                       =   x + "," + y;
    tile.transform.parent           =   transform.FindChild("Filled").transform;
    tile.transform.position         =   position;
    tile.transform.localScale       =   new Vector3(tileSize, tileSize, 70f);
    tile.SetActive(true);

    Debug.Log ("added scale: " + tile.transform.localScale + " x:" + x + " y:" + y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't use Queue tile = new Queue(), things work normally.  I think its a bug.